# Gutenberg editor failing to load correctly after new theme install

Tags: block-editor

We have installed a new theme on our site, but the editor just loads into a single code editor window (best to see the attached).
The old theme did have the gutenberg editor disabled in functions.php, so wondered if this somehow had affected the database?

[image: missgin block editor]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're just seeing Gutenberg in Full Screen Mode (set as default in WP 5.4).

You can turn it off using the More Tools and Options control (the 3 dots in the top right).